# How to search between dates using Jquery and hide the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:
My code has several classes "chat-message"

```
<a href="#" onclick="dateBetweenCheck();">Filter</a>


<div class="chat-message">
  <div class="message">
       <span class="message-date">13/02/2016</span>
       <span class="message-content">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       </span>
  </div>

  <div class="message">
       <span class="message-date">15/02/2016</span>
       <span class="message-content">
         ponderum ullamcorper delicatissimi ex mel
       </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the following Javascript function to go through the .message class and check if the message date is between a start date and a end date.

```
function dateBetweenCheck() {
      var sDate,eDate;
      sDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#startDate').val());
      eDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#endDate').val());
      $(".message").each(function(){
        var messageDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $(this).find(".message-date").text());
        if((messageDate <= eDate && messageDate >= sDate)) {
          $(this).remove();
          return true;
        }
      });

    }
```

How to remove the .message class and its children?
How do I make the .message class appear again when I click the filter button?

Comment: You should be hiding the items (with `.hide()`), not removing them (with `.remove()`). You can't recover a deleted item. To reverse it you just show() them all.

Comment: Have you ever thought about looking at using moment.js? This may shorten the amount of code your are writing. You could put all of your times in an array and look to see if it is in between if so, look for the data-date attribute or special id in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, don't use inline click handlers with jQuery. It separates the handler from the registration for no reason and jQuery gives you more event features.
- In the absence of more info, use a class to indicate whether the filter is applied or not (`active` in this example).
- Use `hide()` and `show()` or `toggle()` to... wait for it... hide, show or toggle items :) Remove takes them out of the DOM forever.

Your HTML should have an ID on the filter:

```
<a href="#" id="dateBetween">Filter</a>
```

And jQuery something like:

```
$('#dateBetween').click(function() {
  var sDate, eDate;

  // The link clicked
  var $link = $(this);

  // Toggle the class that indicates we are filtering
  $link.toggleClass("active");

  // If we are filtering...
  if ($link.hasClass("active")) {

    sDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#startDate').val());
    eDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#endDate').val());

    // Hide or show messages based on the date
    $(".message").each(function() {

      var messageDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $(this).find(".message-date").text());

      // A true expression to toggle does a show(), else hide()
      $(this).toggle(messageDate <= eDate && messageDate >= sDate);
    });
  }
  else
  {
     // Show all messages
     $(".message").show();
  }
  // This causes the filter link to do nothing (otherwise it may move the browser window to the top)
  return false;
});
```